# JAVA Read sample doc file, fill with data and generate PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I am triing to make an automatization program in JAVA. 
I have a sample doc file. I need to fill the blank parts or the <> "signed" parts from database,
than create pdf files.

I tried to read the word :

```
    import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = null;
WordExtractor extractor = null ;
try {

   file = new File("c:\\New.doc");
   FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
   HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
   extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
   String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
   for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++){
     if(fileData[i] != null)
       System.out.println(fileData[i]);
   }
}
catch(Exception exep){}
  }
}
```

but this attemption is bad in many way cause i only need to write some of the parts, and this method make a single test from the doc.

So can you advice me some api that write in a word doc eg: `after Name :` or `in the 5 row write this:`
And when it finish with the word it should generate a pdf and do it again ...

I am looking a solution wich i found xssfworkbook with some extra function ( generate pdf of the doc ).

> Or read the sample pdf and fill with datas and save to a new pdf.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Use Itext (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/)
and Apache POI Project http://poi.apache.org/index.html

A sample code :

```
     import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;

     import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

     import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
     import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
     import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
     import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            String pdfPath = "C:/";
            String pdfDocPath = null;
            try {
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Test.doc"));

                WordExtractor wd = new WordExtractor(is);
                String text = wd.getText();
                /* FOR DOCX
                 // IMPORT
                 import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
                 import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
                 import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
                 // CODE
                 XWPFDocument hdoc  = new XWPFDocument(is);
                 extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(hdoc);

                 String text = extractor.getText();
                */
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfPath + "viewDoc.pdf"));
                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph(text));
                document.close();
                pdfDocPath = pdfPath + "viewDoc.pdf";
                System.out.println("Pdf document path is" + pdfDocPath);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                System.out.println("File does not exist.");
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("IO Exception");
            }
            catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show me your imports, it always give me some error and never read anything always stop at wordextractor